# Implement AKA in SQL Server Master Data Services

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I'm working with a bunch of scientists and we're trying to implement a master data solution for the ingredients they use in formulations. The problem with their historic data is Scientist #1 will use Ingredient A but call it 'Alpha 100' while Scientist #2 will use Ingredient A and call it 'A100'. We want to implement Master Data Services to make sure the way the materials are characterized scientifically is consistent and then develop a template that will force scientists to pick ingredients from a drop down. However, Scientist #1 will be looking for 'Alpha 100' and Scientist #2 will be looking for 'A100' in a dropdown, so I'm curious, **is there a way to implement an AKA (also known as) solution is SQL Server Master Data Services?**

I was thinking it could just be a bunch of extra attributes that can be null and then unpivot them in a view, but that doesn't feel elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a separate entity and a [derived hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/derived-hierarchies-master-data-services?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
Ingredient(Code, Name, ...)

IngredientAKA(Code, Name, Ingredient)
```

Where the Ingredient.Name is the "official" or "canonical" name, and IngredientAKA.Name is has all the alternate names.